# django template, using {% with %} to set a list var

Tags: django, django-templates, sendinblue

I need to hard set a list in django template.
I know that I have to pass variables `to the template`, instead of creating them `in the template`, but I only have access to the template file. I'm using sendinblue with a custom template, and the only way to use custom params injected to the template is to use their api. I only need to hardcode some content in a list, and the content will dynamically appear depending on contact, I think that using an api only for this is overkill.

Comment: maybe try to use javascript insert list vars?

Comment: @ha-neul I forgot to mention that I never use django templates, even if I use other similar template languages. I read the documentation, but I didn't found what I'm looking for, can you be more explicit about your solution?
P.S There's no possibility to use javascript in email templates

Answer (score 0):

```
{% with tt='123'|make_list %}
    {{ tt }}
    <hr>
    {% for x in tt %}
        {{ x }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

try this

Comment: I already found this fiiter in the doc, but my data is more complex than just an array of numbers, or character. It's an array of objects, that I use to compose dynamically the html (there's addresses, phone numbers, names, ...)